# adobe flash layering

Tags: actionscript-2, flash-cs5

im not sure if layering is the correct issue im facing but anyway, here's my problem in detail.

i have created a flash file, with many layers.
i have created buttons on these layers such that on release, it will load another movieclip which acts as a popup window.
the movieclip is loaded and visibily is on upper most layer the but though i am unable to see the buttons below, i am still able to click on them through this loaded movieclip and loads some other stuff scripted on the buttons.

hope i have explained my headache detail enough and hope i can get some advice to go about fixing it.

i tried googling but i got no idea what are the keywords to search for!

---

okay i think my title should have been "flash click through problem".
anyway i have solved it with the following;

> > > > Use a big enough clip on top of everything. Don't disable it though.
> > > >
> > > > > > > `mc_overlay.onRollOver = function() {`
> > > > > > >
> > > > > > > `this.useHandCursor = false; }`

credits to [gotoAndLearn()](http://www.gotoandlearnforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=8639)

cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you'd want to have the playhead go to a different frame that doesn't have those buttons. This might be the best/easiest solution for you.

Comment: i have an emptyclip on a new layer and frame to load the movieclip on release of the buttons already, it doesnt help :(